# Store EditText values in android

Tags: android, database, android-edittext

I developed an android application... in which... users name last name *date of birth*, *mobile number, email id* everything is collected... I wanted to store these details... and when user wants these data's back... a button is there called recall... when user press recall button .. the place where this data's is stored can be displayed.. and he can select his name from this names... any one know how this data can be saved....I am giving the code...here ...anyone pls.. help.. the code is working.... no problem in it...

```
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker  arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
        {

         String date=Integer.toString(arg3);
         String month=Integer.toString(arg2);
         String year=Integer.toString(arg1);

         tv1.setText(date+ month+1 +year);
         tv2.setText(month+1 + year);
         tv3.setText(year);
         tv4.setText(month+1);
         tv5.setText(date);
         tv6.setText(date + year);

        }   

    });}

    public void sum(View v)
    {
        long sum1=0;
        long sum2=0;
        long sum3=0;
        long sum4=0;
        long sum5=0;
        long sum6=0;
        long sum7=0;
        long sum8=0;
        long sum=0;
        long sum11=0;
        long sum12=0;
        long sum13=0;
        long sum14=0;

        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
        EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText4);

        final DatePicker date = (DatePicker) findViewById (R.id.datePicker1);
        final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView88);
        final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView89);
        final TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView90);
        final TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView91);
        final TextView tv5 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView92);
        final TextView tv6 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView93);
        final TextView tv7 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView94);

        sum1=getSum(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString() + et4.getText().toString());
        sum2=getSum1(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString() + et4.getText().toString());
        sum3=getSum2(tv1.getText().toString());
        /*sum4=getSum3(tv2.getText().toString());*/
        sum5=getSum4(tv3.getText().toString());
        sum6=getSum5(tv4.getText().toString());
        sum8=getSum7(tv5.getText().toString());

        String yearf = tv3.getText().toString();
        int yearb = Integer.valueOf(yearf);

        int val = 2013 - yearb;
        long val1 = sum3;
        /*int val2 = Integer.valueOf(val1);*/
        long val3 = 36 - val1;
        int val4 = 9;
        long val5 = val3 + val4;
        long val6 = val5 + val4;
        long val7 = val6 + 50;

        sum = getSum3(tv2.getText().toString()) + getSum8(tv6.getText().toString());

        if (val <= val3)
        {
            sum4=getSum3(tv2.getText().toString());
        }

        else if ((val <= val5) && (val > val3))
        {
            sum4=getSum8(tv6.getText().toString());
        }

        else if ((val<=val6) && (val > val5) && (val > val3))
        {
            /*sum = getSum3(tv2.getText().toString()) + getSum8(tv6.getText().toString());*/
             sum4=getSum9(Integer.toString((int) sum));
        }
        else 
        {
             sum4=getSum9(Integer.toString((int) sum));
        }

        if (val <= val3)
        {

        if (sum5>sum6)
        {
            sum7 = (sum5 - sum6);
        }
        else 
        {
            sum7 = (sum6 - sum5);
        }

        }

        else if ((val <= val5) && (val > val3))
        {
            if(sum5>sum8)
            {
                sum7=(sum5 - sum8);
            }
            else
            {
                sum7 = (sum8 - sum5);
            }
        }


        else if ((val<=val6) && (val > val5) && (val > val3))
        {
            sum11 = (sum5 - sum8);
            sum12 = (sum8 - sum5);
            sum13 = (sum6 - sum5);
            sum14 = (sum5 - sum6);

            if ((sum11 > sum12) && (sum13 > sum14))
            {
                if (sum11 > sum13)
                {
                    sum7 = sum11 - sum13;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = sum13 - sum11;
                }
            }
            else if ((sum12 > sum11) && (sum13 > sum14))
            {
                if (sum12 > sum13)
                {
                    sum7 = sum12 - sum13;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = sum13 - sum12;
                }
            }
            else if ((sum11 > sum12) && (sum14 > sum13))
            {
                if (sum11 > sum14)
                {
                    sum7 = sum11 - sum14;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = sum14 - sum11;
                }
            }
            else if ((sum12 > sum11) && (sum14 > sum13))
            {
                if (sum12 > sum14)
                {
                    sum7 = sum12 - sum14;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = sum14 - sum12;
                }
            }

        }
            else 
            {
                sum11 = (sum5 - sum8);
                sum12 = (sum8 - sum5);
                sum13 = (sum6 - sum5);
                sum14 = (sum5 - sum6);

                if ((sum11 > sum12) && (sum13 > sum14))
                {
                    if (sum11 > sum13)
                    {
                        sum7 = sum11 - sum13;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        sum7 = sum13 - sum11;
                    }
                }
                else if ((sum12 > sum11) && (sum13 > sum14))
                {
                    if (sum12 > sum13)
                    {
                        sum7 = sum12 - sum13;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        sum7 = sum13 - sum12;
                    }
                }
                else if ((sum11 > sum12) && (sum14 > sum13))
                {
                    if (sum11 > sum14)
                    {
                        sum7 = sum11 - sum14;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        sum7 = sum14 - sum11;
                    }
                }
                else if ((sum12 > sum11) && (sum14 > sum13))
                {
                    if (sum12 > sum14)
                    {
                        sum7 = sum12 - sum14;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        sum7 = sum14 - sum12;
                    }
                }

            }


        String edtxt1 = et1.getText().toString();
        String edtxt4 = et4.getText().toString();

        if(edtxt1.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First Name should not be left blank, Please enter your First Name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if(edtxt4.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Last Name should not be left blank, Please enter your Last Name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else{

        Intent i = new Intent(this, result.class);
        i.putExtra("name", sum1 + "");
        i.putExtra("name1", sum2 + "");
        i.putExtra("name2", sum3 + "");
        i.putExtra("name3", sum4 + "");
        i.putExtra("name4", sum7 + "");

        startActivity(i);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). But if this isn't for a lot of users you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). That link has a good example of getting started using them.

If you are going to have multiple users with that much different pieces of data then you may want to look at using [SQLite DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). If you aren't used to using SQLite Db then [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) might be a good one to get you started.

You also could use the other storage options in the link I provided but a DB would probably be the best with storing a lot of different information for different users.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using SharedPreferences?

You can store any variable with the SharedPreferences and it's super easy! 
Here's a quick tutorial

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      getApplicationContext(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
String dateTimeKey = "com.example.app.datetime";
// use a default value using new Date()
    long l = prefs.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

To edit and save preferences

```
Date dt = getSomeDate();
prefs.edit().putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime()).commit();
```